# How do i read message content in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

What i want to do is get the stats of an osu! player. However i do not know how to read message content after the $getstats command.

```
osu_url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/users/'


if message.content.startswith('$getstats'):
    player_name = #read content after $getstats
    osu_url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/users/' + player_name
```

Can anyone explain how to read message content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possiable soultion, spliting the string by `$getstats`.

```py
osu_url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/users/'

if message.content.startswith('$getstats'):
    _, player_name = message.content.split('$getstats')
    osu_url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/users/' + player_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
player_name = message.content[9:]
```

Where `9 = len("$getstats")`